# Dropdown button to output value from database when clicked, on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, sql, python-3.x, jinja2

Sorry, I won't upload the whole code to avoid plagiarism, because this is my uni project, but I just want to ask a simple question.
So basically I have a database with stored sensor data. Then I have a Python file and html file. In Python file I have imported the following libraries and modules:
cherrypy, sqlite3 and jinja2. So I connect my database via python with codes, like select * from... Then in html I have the code to style my dropdown button and here is the dropdown button itself:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="sound_hist()" class="dropbtn">Previous sound data</button>
        <div id="soundData" class="dropdown-content">
            {% for d in dates %}
                <a href="">{{d}}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Which creates a dropdown button on my home page and that button, when clicked, has 4 options to choose from, 4 dates. But thing is, I am not sure if it is possible at all, to makes such a thing, so when the particular date has been chosen, i.e the button was clicked, the data from the database would have been shown on the same page? The database itself has 4 columns: row, date, time and data. So I want to click any option(date) in my dropdown and when clicked, on the same page, near the button, I would be able to see the time and data that my sensor had on that date. But at the moment , I am doubting that this is possible to do at all. Can someone help, please?

Comment: You may want to use the [tag:cherrypy] tag if you are interested in a solution specific to that framework.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with some simple Javascript as shown in the example below, but the data has to be included in the Javascript. This may not be possible in your situation.

I suggest looking at the [tutorials on the CherryPy website](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html). The Ajax and React tutorials would probably be the most helpful if you want to obtain data from the server.

```
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    var sensorData = {
      Jan1: "January 1st Data",
      Jan2: "January 2nd Data",
      Jan3: "January 3rd Data"
    };

    function updateText() {
      var options = document.getElementById('dates');
      var display = document.getElementById('display')
      display.innerHTML = sensorData[options.value];
    }
  </script>

  <select id="dates" onchange="updateText()">
    <option value="Jan1">January 1</option>
    <option value="Jan2">January 2</option>
    <option value="Jan3">January 3</option>
  </select>

  <div id="display">Display Data Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```